# How stop Ubuntu from reading my password out loud every time I log on?

Tags: password, logging

I turned on a certain feature on the login screen and now my password is read out loud when I type it on login. What did I turn on, and how do I turn this back off?

Comment: It doesn't do that 'out of the box', in my experience.  What did you toggle or turn on recently?

Comment: Last time I turned on this computer before Christmas, so I don't remember :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is probably the Orca screen reader that does this. Turn it off if you do not want this to happen.

(hit dash and search for orca)

Oh and it is possible you turned it on, by accident, at the login screen.

#### 14.04. LTS

[image]

#### 16.04. LTS

[image]

Make sure *"Screen Reader"* is unticked.

Comment: @takkat Thanks. I was wondering how to make a login screenshot

Comment: That'll be [my secret](http://askubuntu.com/tags/virtualbox/topusers) ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind – run Ubuntu in a virtual machine, and you can make a screen-shot of the login page.