# Why is my computer reading to me when I am putting in my password?

Tags: 14.04, accessibility

It reads to me! I have never turned any reading mechanism on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How stop Ubuntu from reading my password out loud every time I log on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/234443/how-stop-ubuntu-from-reading-my-password-out-loud-every-time-i-log-on)

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/278693/how-do-i-stop-orca-screen-reader

Answer (score 2):

### Orca

> Orca is a free, open source, flexible, extensible, and powerful assistive technology for people with visual impairments. Using various combinations of speech synthesis and Braille, Orca helps provide access to applications and toolkits that support the assistive technology service provider interface (AT-SPI), e.g. the GNOME desktop and Unity. The development of Orca has been led by Joanmarie Diggs at Igalia, with contributions from many community members.
>
> from [Accessibility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Accessibility)

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is a shortcut to enable/disable **Orca**.

(<kbd>Super</kbd> is either the Windows Key or Command Key depending on your hardware)

If you press that shortcut it should stop the text to speech functionality. You may have pressed that combination together by mistake.

Comment: It is `CTRL + S` in 14.04